# How can a google static map be saved as an image that can be used not just the URL to googles api

Tags: ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

How can a google static map be saved as an image that can be used not just the URL to Google's API?

Sorry if this as been answered somewhere but everywhere I look people point to the static map quick example but  this is not good as it's the saving of the static map that I need to find out.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Static Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

This tool might be of use to use to you as well: http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/snapshotcontrol/1.0/examples/optionsWizard.html

Comment: the link tool is not available any more

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this is what i've used.

http://www.prodraw.net/online-tool/google-maps-image-generator.php

you can use address or GPS location to generate that section of the map, change the color of the pointer as well as the zoom level.

Once completed, you have the option to either link to that image or save the image.

Answer (score -1):

Just take a screenshot of the map and save as JPG

If you want this image to link to somewhere, wrap it in an `<a>` tag